How to run only tagged scenarios in azure pipeline using SpecFlow
I have a lot of testcases in SpecFlow for my website. There are different wizards in this website and I have created a tag for testcases associated with each, since changing something in the code of one shouldn't affect any of the others. I want to have the option in my Azure pipeline that when I run it I can select which tests to run in T based on the tags. Does anyone know how to do this?

You cand following the steps below to configure your project:

In the code of your solution, ensure you have installed the SpecFlow+ Runner NuGet Package for the test projects. This package contains all necessary integration components.

In the test projects, use SpecFlow+ Runner as unit test provider.

In the feature file of your test projects, set different tags for different scenarios.

When you run the tests in Azure pipelines:

If you use the Visual Studio Test task (VSTest@3), you can use the option 'testFiltercriteria' (Test filter criteria) to specify tags.
- task: VSTest@3
  displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
  inputs:
    testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory=tag01 & TestCategory=tag02'



If you use the .NET Core task (DotNetCoreCLI@2), you can use the option 'arguments' (Arguments) to specify a filter expression with specific tags.
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet test'
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: 'path/to/test-project.csproj'
    arguments: '--filter "TestCategory=tag01 & TestCategory=tag02"'






Related documentations:

Executing specific Scenarios in your Build pipeline
Run selected unit tests



I've gotten this to work using the Visual Studio Test task as well, but it is the same basic principle. You need to filter the test cases based on the TestCategory. I guess my remark is more aimed at the fact you do not need the SpecFlow+ Runner to achieve this.

@GregBurghardt, Yes, you are correct. SpecFlow also supports MsTest V2 (see here). And using SpecFlow+ Runner is just another way.
